# Filtering a Calculated Model in Google App Maker

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have a `calculated model` with survey responses from Google Form and Directory information for each of the submissions. This model filters the results so as to return only the **LATEST** submission, where users have submitted multiple times.

I'm using an `Accordion widget` to display this info and I would like from the `Details panel` to create a `popup` that will display `ALL of the responses for the Selected User in the Accordion`.

[Current Accordion UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vItso.png)

What's the best way to return only the values associated with the opened accordion card - see screenshot? e.g. John Doe's previous answers

[Popup outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MICat.png)

I tried using the bindings but I always get ALL the results for ALL the users in the same order as the Accordion and when I select a row it also selects the accordion row.

Any advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** You definitely need two different datasources (maybe even models), since you cannot reuse the same datasource for different widgets.

App Maker's datacource concept is different from classic ajax request. With classic XMLHttpRequest you can populated multiple result sets and use them wherever you want whereas adjusting query filters and reloading datasource with App Maker will just update `items` collection and rerender all widgets bound to the datasource.